# Component render two times (reactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I have a React Component, when I compile it it renders two times. Some idea?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default () => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      {console.log("test")}
      {alert("y")}
      <h2>Cargando</h2>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Specifically, you need to recreate as simply as you can, a new application that causes the same behavior. This needs to include code that uses this component so we can see how it is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using `React.StrictMode`, right?

Read about it here https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

It has special mechanism to detect side-effects so in development mode some components will render 2 times instead of one. But it could also happen in production unintentionally but you really should not care about how many times render happened.

Comment: True , in my "index.js" I have defined the "React.StrictMode", is it important to have StrictMode activated?

Comment: It's nice to have, it can help you spot some potentially unsafe stuff. But sometimes you are in situation with lots of libraries that not yet follow StrictMode and there is just too much warnings. Up to you, but basically it's better to have it than not!

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that it renders two times? Because of console.log? It just means that inner mechanisms of react call rendering two times... You should not care about it. It can be called even 10 times if necessary